# Photoshop text Library

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, adobe-library

I work on a lot of projects where I have to put little spans of text in big paragraphs. These spans are always a - and a capitol letter. I've been trying to make a library of these spans like, -A, -B, -C where the dash is black and the letter is a different color in a different font than what I normally type.

My hope with the libraries is that I can type a sentence and click on the element in the library to insert the -A formatted the way I want it and then go back to typing in the usual font.

Is this even possible? Are there any workarounds or ways to get close to this?

Answer (score 1):

The best you're going to get is using the Paragraph and Character Styles which I believe was added in CS6. Type your text:

> A-Body of text and whatever content belongs here.

Change it to a Paragraph Style to save time overall.

Then highlight A- and click on a Character Style to quickly change it to right font and color.

[image]

Beyond this you'll need to start using a Page Layout program such as InDesign.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is putting me on the right track. In InDesign I use grep to detect the -1 or -A and format it on the fly. I wish Photoshop had that option or InDesign could integrate with After Effects better.